# ajaxUrl is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

When I push a green button on http://jazzkredit.ru/ after submission form, I get message "ajaxUrl is not defined" instead of image that should pop up and email that I should receive on email.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue? I have tried to search for an answer on Google and in Stackoverflow but it didn't help.

```
var formData = new FormData($('form#loanappform')[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,  //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    //Ajax events
    success: completeHandler,
    // Form data
    data: formData,
    //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

Comment: _"ajaxUrl is not defined"_ what this means that you have referenced a variable which is does not have anything assigned.

Comment: What do you have in the ajaxUrl? Try printing it out in console to see if it has the URL!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define ajaxUrl first or just use the direct name of the server-side file to which you are posting:
Method A: `var ajaxUrl = "process-ajax.php"`
Method B: `url: "process-ajax.php"`